# Node.js+VUE.JSにてリクエストヘッダにX-Forwarded-forを付与してバックエンドにPOSTしたい

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack

題記の通りです。
現状webpackの設定ファイルにproxyを設定し特定のアドレスパターンの場合はバックエンドサーバに通信しているのですがそのときにリクエストヘッダにX-Forwarded-forとしてリモートアドレスを付与してPOSTしたいのですがどこにどのような設定をすればよいのかわかりません。
ご教示ください

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebPackのDevServerはproxyを利用してください

```
devServer:{
  proxy:{
    onProxyReq:function(proxyReq,req,res){
       proxyReq.setHeader("X-Forwarded-for",req.connection.remoteAddress);
    }
  }
}
```

Webpackでビルドしたものを動かす場合はserver.jsにて

```
app.use(ルート,
  createProxyMiddleware({
      target: <ターゲット>,
      onProxyRequest:(proxyReq,req,res)=>{
        proxyReq.setHeader("X-Forwarded-for",req.connection.remoteAddress);
      }
  })
);
```